# What's the name of the color for the current item in the VS XAML editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Ok. I am finding it difficult to visually discern where the current focus of my editor is. The image below shows that I am currently in the bottom PathIcon tag while the top PathIcon tag is highlighted because it is a matching type. The similarity in color has finally driven me crazy.

[image]

Does anyone know the correct text-type in the Fonts and Colors dialog of Visual Studio 2015 to change this color? *And, look, for all the StackOverflow haters trolling the board, please resist closing this q until there is an answer. Then you can have your fun.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are actually two different colors in play here. The grey box on the "<PathIcon" that contains the cursor is "Brace Matching (Rectangle)". The purplish box on the other "PathIcon" looks like it is the background portion of the "Match color", which is installed by the pro power tools.

The latter color won't reset if you change the color in fonts and colors but will be correct for editor instances you open after changing the color.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Highlight Current Line (Active)`, which controls the colors of the line your cursor is on.

Comment: That actually highlights the entire line, and not the current item. In the image, see how PathIcon is highlighted? That's what I am trying to influence, not the whole line. However, I do like highlighting the line. Nice suggestion.